# IndexOf not finding string in text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've this `<p>` that contains characters wrapped with a `<span>` that in total form a sentence. Now I need to insert some `<br/>` at several unknown positions in the `<p>` where certain words are positioned. To do this I wrote a function:

```
function spaceInsert() {
    var sentence = [ 'spirit of brotherhood.' ];

    for( var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++ ) {
      console.log( sentence[i] );
      console.log( $( '#body .tattoo-letters' ).text() );
      console.log( $( '#body .tattoo-letters' ).text().indexOf( sentence[i] ) );
    }
}
```

the `sentence` array contains the sentences which need a breakline. Why is indexOf returning -1 ( not found? ). I am logging the text and it is in there.

EDIT

The text in the console - second console log ( it is appended, so can't show any html ).
`All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights. They are endowed with reason and conscience and should act towards one another in a spirit of brotherhood.Everyone is entitled to all the rights and freedoms set forth in this Declaration, without distinction of any kind, such as race, colour, sex, language, religion, political or other opinion, national or social origin, property, birth or other status. Furthermore, no distinction shall be made on the basis of the political, jurisdictional or international status of the country or territory to which a person belongs, whether it be independent, trust, non-self-governing or under any other limitation of sovereignty.`

Comment: What does `$( '#body .tattoo-letters' ).text()` return?

Comment: Please add your HTML so we can see exactly what text is being retrieved.

Comment: The text is appended. But the console print is - see edit @Satpal

Comment: why is sentence an Array rather then a String ? You are passing each letter to indexOf inside of an entire word / sentence

Comment: Because I need multiple sentences getting an breakline appended after it. So I can now add multiple sentences to the array if I want.

Comment: `You are passing each letter to indexOf inside of an entire word / sentence` No he isn't he's taking the first element of the array, in this case `'spirit of brotherhood'`

Comment: Yep, I stand corrected. didn't read it properly.

Comment: try remove `body`, http://jsfiddle.net/tw24rg9h/ look at console

Comment: OP, your code works fine in a fiddle given the information you've shown us: http://jsfiddle.net/qhzgq62f/. To help solve your issue we need a more complete working demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Doesn't do the magic :( @Waki

Comment: your selector is wrong please check $( '#body .tattoo-letters' )

Comment: it works http://jsfiddle.net/2ba4d79w/1/

Comment: It's because the spaces are non-breaking not normal whitespace.

Comment: @JqueryKing newpe not the solution and used to have it like that but above someone suggested that I remove it

Comment: @Phylogenesis where is that coming from? How can I solve it?

Comment: show your html source in question

Comment: See my answer, Krijn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example, the following works:

```
$( '.tattoo-letters' ).text().indexOf('spirit\u00a0of\u00a0brotherhood.')
```

The spaces in your HTML are non-breaking whitespace (U+00A0).

Answer (score 0):

Try this  i have checked on  your site

```
function spaceInsert() {
    var sentence = [ 'spirit of brotherhood.' ];

    for( var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++ ) {
      console.log( sentence[i] );
      console.log( $( '#body .tattoo-letters' ).text() );
      console.log(  $("<div />").html($( '#body .tattoo-letters' ).text().trim()).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g," ").indexOf( sentence[i] )  );
    }
}
```